# Pick $x$ out of $y$ objects. Match $n$ picks.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Computer randomly picks a group of 6 objects out of 30, no repetitions.
User than picks $6$ objects out of those $30$, also no repetitions.

What are the odds of the user getting $3$ of his picks to match objects in the group the computer chose?
Can you give a general formula for this type of problem?

Comment: Where's your attempt ?

Comment: $\frac{\frac{\binom{6}{3}*\binom{24}{3}}{2} }{\binom{30}{6} }$

Comment: @OrrSiloni: are you looking for the odds of exactly $3$ matches or *at least* $3$ matches?

Comment: @Amir- I think your answer needs to get rid of the division by $2$. Then I believe it's correct for exactly $3$ matches.

Comment: @ColmBhandal: I meant exactly 3 matches.

Comment: Ah. In that case the answer of @miniparser is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

this is a probability problem.  from probability perspective can look at it in terms of events.  assuming you want exactly $3$ matches.  event $B$ is 'user picks $6$ objects of the $30$.'  event $A$ is 'user picks $3$ of the objects the computer chose.'  $A$ intersects $B$ is 'user picks $3$ of the same objects as the computer and $3$ more from remaining.'

$Pr(A|B)={Pr({A\cap B})\over Pr(B)}={{{6\choose 3}{24\choose 3}}\over{30\choose 6}}$

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to choose $6$ from $30$ is $30 \choose 6$. This is the total amount of possibilities for the user's choice.

Now, the number of choices where there are at least $3$ matches is that there are either $3$, $4$, $5$ or $6$ matches. Call this number $M$. Then we get:

$$M = {6 \choose 3} \times {24 \choose 3} + {6 \choose 4} \times {24 \choose 2} + {6 \choose 5} \times {24 \choose 1} + 1$$

In general, this formula is:

$$M = \sum_{i = r}^{k} {k \choose i} \times {n - k \choose k - i}$$

where $n$ is the total number of objects, $k$ is the number of user (and computer) choices and $r$ is the minimum number of matches required.

The total number of choices, call it $C$ is $n \choose k$. So the odds are:

$$\frac{M}{C}$$

Comment: You should notice that it's not important that you choose the first 3  of 6 and then  3 of 24 . you should do divide 2 your answer.

Comment: Edit in progress...

Answer (score -2):

Some problems are answered mathematically , some logically.

If you have 9,763 black socks and 1,845,963 white socks,if you randoml pick out 3 socks, you will have a pair of either white or black socks.

I am not really sure I understand the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid your answer doesn't really address the question. Also, generally, when you don't understand a question, you should ask for clarification in a comment under the question, rather than in an answer.

Comment: Agreed with above. Please consider removing this answer as it is misleading.